# Saving streaming data to file before processing

Tags: perl

I use a Perl script to open and connect to a socket. I am receiving streaming [NMEA 0183](http://www.nmea.org/content/nmea_standards/nmea_0183_v_410.asp) data on it which I process and add to a MySQL database in real time.

I want to save the incoming raw data to a text file prior to processing as I want to check that the data is being written to the database correctly.

Any advice on how to do it?

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/writing-to-files-with-perl

Answer (score 0):

Are you completely unfamilar with Perl?

At the start of the program, add

```
open my $raw_fh, '>:raw', 'rawdata.bin' or die $!;
```

Then, when each packet arrives, add

```
print $raw_fh $packet;
```

before it is passed to be processed.